# How Lucene reduces CPU usage over full-text search of sql server?

Tags: sql-server, lucene, memcached, full-text-search

I had read article about how stackoverflow reduced its CPU usage by using lucene.

But my question is how ?

Is it due to caching of lucene ?

and if yes. If we implement a sqlserver fts with memcache. will it be same as lucene ?

or does Lucene uses different data structures for search ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lucene is using indexing and full text search - it's more than caching.

SQL is a set-based relational language.  It's not built for ad hoc queries of documents.  The technology is completely different.

Comment: @dyffymo Is using fts of sqlserver/ sqlite http://www.sqlite.org/draft/fts3.html will not create index and full-text search ?

Comment: Is that the version SO is using?  The fact that SO explicitly said they were using Lucene suggests to me that there was no other way for them to get the functionality it provides.  Your citation means adding what Lucene does into a SQL relational engine.  It's not native to the technology.

Comment: @dyffymo ok , thanks. why I asked was that I need to choose one from database fts over lucene in my project. so I thought that lucene will reduce cpu usages over sqlite fts search.